# Use Grails production mode with Intellij IDEA

Tags: grails, intellij-idea

I try to running a grails application in production mode, I see the tutorial in Grails homepage, but I don't have the selectable "configuration Type".

I have a Grails Script parameter field, try to use "production word", but it change nothing ; always in development mode.
An idea to force "production mode" with intelliJ IDEA ?

Thanks

Note : using IDEA 8.1.3.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you are doing it via a Run Configuration you can add `-Dgrails.env=prod` in the VM parameters section. If you're using the Run Grails Script command I don't think there is anyway to do it.

You should try out the latest EAP, it has better run support than the old 8.1 version.